# (Not an issue) In CartThrob, how can I delete an item from the cart by updating it's quantity to 0?

Tags: cartthrob, add-on

**Edit:** This appears to work out of the box, as long as everything is set up and coded correctly. See my comment below.

Using {exp:cartthrob:update_cart_form}, is there a way to make items with an updated quantity of 0 reliably delete from the cart when the form is submitted?

I can't find any documentation or postings on this question, but I'm hoping there is a way. It makes no sense to me that a customer can update their quantity to any other number, but 0 has no effect. Setting a quantity to 0 *should* bring the same result as calling delete.

In my testing, if I have a cart with multiple items, the last item listed will sometimes delete from the cart if I update it's quantity to 0. However, this is inconsistent. Setting quantity to 0 on any other item in the cart has no effect.

Comment: Post your template code maybe. Works fine here, even ajax submitting the firm.  My guess is your form fields have mismatching ids maybe...

Comment: @JeremyDaalder You're right, I think there was something wrong with my original code in the template. After I posted my question, I did a bunch of tweaking on other items and it seems to have also fixed my original issue in the process. Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly which change(s) inadvertently resolved this issue, so I can't share any lessons learned.